# Messages App in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, messages

I know that there exists an iOS simulator for Mac (how to get it eludes me - if you could give me a download link I'd be grateful).

Many people want to know how to use multiple Apple IDs with Messages.  Can I use the Messages app inside the iOS simulator to run a second Apple ID?

Mac OS X 10.11.2
2011 Mac  Mini

Comment: Are you referring to the iPhone simulator in Xcode? If so then you can't use the iMessage in it.

Comment: Yes I am, and that's disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to create a User account for yourself, separate from your Mom & Dad's acccount. This would let you have your own Apple ID in Messages, as well as your own documents, preferences, etc.

Go to System Preferences, click on "Users & Groups", unlock to authorize, and add a new User by clicking the "+" button.

More information about multiple users can be found here:
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18891?locale=en_US

Comment: Already knew all this would work, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Update: I got my own MBP.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.  The Messages app is actually in Xcode, the Apple development environment.  Within Xcode are the iPhone, iPad, and Mac simulators.  Apple prevents the simulators from sending actual messages.  I have created iOS apps that send messages so I've tried doing this many, many times.  Each time you try to send a message you'll receive an error stating `Cannot Send Message`.

Comment: Why is Apple trying to keep us from using Messages with more than one Apple ID?

Comment: @Daniel I would assume that Apple is trying to encourage everyone to put all of their information under one Apple ID. If you want to send and receive texts from different emails you can add them under the same Apple ID and specifically chose which ones to send and receive from.

Comment: I just test in a real device using multiple ID's, just like @slightly_toasted mentioned.  If you do that you can get around the limitation.  Either way, you can't send messages via the simulator.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get around the fact that this is a shared computer, with my Mom's Apple ID being used for everything.  I'd like to be able to use Messages in my Apple ID, but I'd have to log her out of everything and she can never remember her password anyways.  I mean, I could create another user account but that seems a little overkill for just Messages.  Is there any way I could run a second copy of Messages.app with a different plist set?

Comment: @Daniel I can't specifically answer that question because I never tried it.  However, all my research into this when I was making my app led to the conclusion that it can't be done with multiple ID's.  I'm sure someone here might know of a hack to get it done, but I don't think it's possible out of the box.

Comment: Well, at least there *is* a solution, making another UID.  I love Apple, but sometimes their proposed solutions don't cut it.